# Auto mount remote NTFS drive on local system

Tags: ssh, ntfs, sshfs

I have an NTFS drive on PC-A that I would like automatically mounted on PC-B on startup or through a launcher so that I can access through Nautilus etc..

PC-A and PC-B are both running Natty Narwhal.
PC-A  is running openssh-server with public private key authentication with a passphrase.

I came accross SSHFS, but I cant figure out how to go about setting it up with a  remote NTFS drive or even if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple really,  I just permanently mounted the NTFS drive on the remote system by editing the *fstab* file and then mounted it locally using *sshfs*, now I just need to write a script to automate the local mounting.